# What is the general idea of Spatial Cox Process?

Tags: spatial

I can't seem to understand the whole idea of Cox Process in spatial point pattern. Can someone explain it in layman's term? thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you understand what an intensity function of a point process is.

This is from p380 of Statistical Analysis and Modelling of Spatial Point Patterns by Illian et al (2008).

> recall  the inhomogeneous Poisson process, based on a non-constant intensity function $\lambda(x)$ [$x \in \mathbb{R_2}$ for example] ... In a stationary Cox process the intensity function is replaced by a stationary random field with non-negative values.  The realisations of this random field are functions which are treated as intensity functions of inhomogeneous Poisson processes

You can think of a random field as like a random variable, except each realisation of the random field is itself a function of space.  So for random field $\{\Lambda(x)\}$, a specific realisation is some $\lambda(x)$ intensity function.  Just like the number $x = 0$ might be a realisation of some random variable $X$.  Except here it is a function of space.

So a Cox process replaces an inhomogenous $\lambda(x)$ with a whole family of possible intensity functions that are described by the random field $\{\Lambda(x)\}$.  There are various options for what $\{\Lambda(x)\}$ actually is.  I work with a log-Gaussian random field with some spatial structure (so you get some smoothness).  The log is to avoid negative values which don't make sense for an intensity function.